# identityserver3 asp.net 5 mvc6 returnurls in client setup

Tags: installation, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3

When setting up the clients in on the server side, the examples I see have a `http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc` return value.

- Where does this come from?
- Am I supposed to create a controller and action for it?

When I use it I get an internal server error and when I remove it I get the client is unknown or is not authorized.

I am trying to use implicit flow with a response type of `id_token` token.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you please post your code so that people can reproduce your error? Or at least describe in detail what it is that you're doing.

Comment: @Aleksander Lidtke i got it working thanks anyway just the url was wrong